# OpenERP 7 one2many pagination

Tags: odoo

I used one2many field in my module to display a tree view,
but there's no pagination for the list and the list become so long.

when I check the previous version of OpenERP(6.1) the pagination is there by default.
how to enable it in OpenERP 7 ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no pagination feature in OpenERP v7 for One2Many widget. It was there in v6 and v6.1.

Comment: that's too bad considering how useful it can be..
thanks for your reply dude,

Answer (score 0):

In openerp 7 The pagination is setup from openerp/addons/web/static/src/js/view_list.js  in line number 117.

```
limit: function () {
    if (this._limit === undefined) {
        this._limit = (this.options.limit
                    || this.defaults.limit
                    || (this.getParent().action || {}).limit
                    || 80);  // is the limit
    }
```

There is setup a limit 80 in default openerp 7. If we change this value it will reflect all one2many fields.